# how to evaluate $\tan x-\cot x=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, problem-solving

**Question**

how to evaluate $\tan x-\cot x=2.$

Given that it lies between on $\left[\frac{-\pi} 2,\frac \pi 2 \right]$.

*My Steps so far*

I converted cot into tan to devolve into $\frac{\tan^2 x-1}{\tan x}=2$.

Then I multiply $\tan{x}$ on both sides and then get $\tan^2 x-2\tan x-1$.

From there I dont know where to go.

Comment: Let $u = \text{tan}(x)$. Solve the new equation for $u$.

Comment: Often people here write "Solve" when "Evalutate" is appropriate, but here you've got "Evaluate" where "Solve" is appropriate.

Comment: Also, your sentence "Given that it lies ..." would be clearer if written as "Given that $x$ lies ...".

Comment: @quasi that is too frivolous. I think that the spirit of the post is what matters. Please stay on topic of math not grammar. and I think that U sub is useless in this scenario, please show me how you did it

Comment: "$u$ sub" is not useless in this scenario. Please refrain from being mean to people who are trying to help you

Comment: And the final line of the work you show is missing the RHS of the equation (i.e., it should be $\text{...} = 0$).

Comment: @John Rawls -- my suggestion to make a subsitution $u = \text{...}$ and solve for $u$, was intended as a hint, not a worked solution.

Comment: @quasi my apologies i figured out the U sub, i thought u meant to do U sub from the beginning of the problem

Comment: @John Rawls -- No problem. The trick of a replacing a common subexpression by a new variable, so as to make the expression easier to work with, is an option you should always be on the lookout for. Having said that, Ramanujan's solution is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We then can solve the quadratic equation thus getting  $$\tan x =\frac {2 \pm \sqrt{4-4 (1)(-1)}}{2} = \frac {2\pm 2\sqrt {2}}{2} = 1\pm \sqrt {2} $$ Thus $$x =\arctan ( 1\pm \sqrt {2}) $$ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

$\tan x - \cot x =2$

$\dfrac{\sin x }{\cos x} - \dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x }=2$

$\dfrac{\sin^2 x - \cos ^2 x}{\sin x \cos x } =2$

$-\cos 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$

$-\cos 2x=\sin2x$

$\tan 2x=-1$

$2x= n\pi -\frac{\pi}{4}$

Put n values to get values of x in required range .

Answer (score 4):

$\tan x$ and $\cot x$ are each other's reciprocals. Let $u=\tan x,$ so that $\dfrac 1 u = \cot x.$

Then $\tan x - \cot x = 2$ becomes $u - \dfrac 1 u = 2,$ and multiplying both sides by $u$ yields $u^2 - 1 = 2u,$ a quadratic equation. You get $u=1\pm\sqrt2.$

Next, if $\tan x= 1+\sqrt2,$ then what is $x$? Perhaps just expressing this as a value of the arctangent function suffices.

Comment: (+1)  Your answer was the first posted.  It has far more information content than the "accepted answer," and yet was pushed down the stack.  I continue to be bewildered by voting behavior herein.  Oh and Happy New Year Michael!  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV. Hi, Mark ! Happy New Year ! I fully agree with your comment.